# Spring- Request method returning a list of objects is showing error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to return a a list of objects to the `/data` endpoint.
Below is the code for the rest controller:

```
@RestController
public class ApiController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home() {
        return "<h1>Welcome to Spring REST API</h1>";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/data", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody List<UserData> data() {
        return new UserService().getData();
    }

}
```

Code for the service:

```
public class UserService {

    private List<UserData> data;

    public UserService() {
        this.data = new ArrayList<UserData>();
        this.data.add(new UserData(1, "Leanne Graham", "bret", "Sincere@april.biz", "Romaguera-Crona", "hildegard.org",
                "1-770-736-8031 x56442"));
        this.data.add(new UserData(2, "Ervin Howell", "Antonette", "Shanna@melissa.tv", "Deckow-Crist", "anastasia.net",
                "010-692-6593 x09125"));
        this.data.add(new UserData(3, "Clementine Bauch", "Samantha", "Nathan@yesenia.net", "Romaguera-Jacobson",
                "ramiro.info", "1-463-123-4447"));
        this.data.add(new UserData(4, "Patricia Lebsack", "Karianne", "Julianne.OConner@kory.org", "Robel-Corkery",
                "kale.biz", "1-770-736-8037"));
        this.data.add(new UserData(5, "Chelsey Dietrich", "Kamren", "Lucio_Hettinger@annie.ca", "Keebler LLC",
                "demarco.info", "1-344-736-8031 x564"));
    }

    /**
     * @return the data
     */
    public List<UserData> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    /**
     * @param data the data to set
     */
    public void setData(List<UserData> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

UserData code:

```
public class UserData {

    int id;
    String name, username, email, company, website, phone;

    public UserData(int id, String name, String username, String email, String company, String website, String phone) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.company = company;
        this.website = website;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

}
```

The UserData class is used to represent individual data to be passed in the list.

The following error and exceptions are thrown:

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path
>   [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException:
>   Type definition error: [simple type, class
>   com.example.springrest.UserData]; nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No
>   serializer found for class com.example.springrest.UserData and no
>   properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception,
>   disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference
>   chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])] with root cause

Comment: can you add your UserData code and which serializer do you use?

Comment: make sure all your fields in UserData has proper getters.

Comment: I have used no serializer... I am a beginner to Spring. Whatis a serializer.. I am adding the UserData code.

Comment: Thanks @Jimmy... Adding getters and setters worked.

Comment: And also please use `@Autowire`for dependency injection, don't create objects outside of context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

Code for controller

```
@RestController
public class ApiController {

    @AutoWired
    UserService userservice;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home() {
        return "<h1>Welcome to Spring REST API</h1>";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/data", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<UserData> data() {
        return new userservice.getData();
    }

}
```

Code for service

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    private List<UserData> data;

    public UserService() {
        this.data = new ArrayList<UserData>();
        this.data.add(new UserData(1, "Leanne Graham", "bret", "Sincere@april.biz", "Romaguera-Crona", "hildegard.org",
                "1-770-736-8031 x56442"));
        this.data.add(new UserData(2, "Ervin Howell", "Antonette", "Shanna@melissa.tv", "Deckow-Crist", "anastasia.net",
                "010-692-6593 x09125"));
        this.data.add(new UserData(3, "Clementine Bauch", "Samantha", "Nathan@yesenia.net", "Romaguera-Jacobson",
                "ramiro.info", "1-463-123-4447"));
        this.data.add(new UserData(4, "Patricia Lebsack", "Karianne", "Julianne.OConner@kory.org", "Robel-Corkery",
                "kale.biz", "1-770-736-8037"));
        this.data.add(new UserData(5, "Chelsey Dietrich", "Kamren", "Lucio_Hettinger@annie.ca", "Keebler LLC",
                "demarco.info", "1-344-736-8031 x564"));
    }

    /**
     * @return the data
     */
    public List<UserData> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    /**
     * @param data the data to set
     */
    public void setData(List<UserData> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```